# Intelligent life from trial by wildfires

Tags: evolution, climate, civilization, intelligence

In my question:

[Sustainability of Regular Global Wildfires Due to Oxygen Rich Atmosphere](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/164174/sustainability-of-regular-global-wildfires-due-to-oxygen-rich-atmosphere)

An answer was proposed for a kind of "Boom Bust Cycle".

The atmosphere has little CO2 but a lot of O2. When land plants use up all the CO2, O2 levels get so high wildfires start but never go out. This purges the land and releases nutrients and carbon back into the atmosphere, and in turn, into the oceans. This allows sea life to bloom until they die bringing carbon back to the land.

Intelligent life requires harsh changes in conditions, but this is pretty tough not to mention regular, every few decades.

Could a migratory or coastal civilization appear in a world like this?

If not, I could say that this is a recent occurrence, similar to the Carboniferous Period.

Answer (score 2):

The boom cycles Willk describes in your previous question are excellent, but not necessarily all-including.

Regular wildfires to purge your world could occur at a large scale, but there will always be areas that are exempt from this cycle. Think islands at which the fires don't start several cycles in a row, or rocky areas with little growth patches, etc. It is certainly possible for an amphibious animal to evolve in areas like these where plant life is permanent, and eventually expand throughout the world due to lack of living space when they increase in numbers.

The fire cycles might even contribute to the development of higher intelligence, since creativity and problem solving skills are preferable in environments like this. They might indeed be migratory, but I would personally put my money on coastal and fortified.

Please note that if you develop an animal population in your world, they will constantly produce CO2, and due to the abundance of sea resources available, ocean life will boom and the balance you have now might slowly be offset by the CO2 producers, and the atmosphere might stabilise itself eventually similar to earth-like conditions. Whether this happens before or after intelligent life evolves is impossible to say.